# Oracle Apex second Trigger on table throwing mutating error

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have table p_it_people with structure as below and trigger created on it.

```
CREATE TABLE  "P_IT_PEOPLE" 
   (    "PERSON_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERSON_NAME" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERSON_EMAIL" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERSON_ROLE" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ASSIGNED_DEPT" NUMBER, 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "PERSON_PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "APPROVER" VARCHAR2(50), 
     CONSTRAINT "P_IT_PEOPLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PERSON_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "P_IT_PEOPLE_NAME_UK" UNIQUE ("PERSON_NAME")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "P_IT_PEOPLE_USERNAME_UK" UNIQUE ("USERNAME")
```

Existing trigger on the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "P_IT_PEOPLE_BIU" 
before insert or update on p_it_people
for each row
begin
if inserting then
if :NEW.PERSON_ID is null then
:NEW.PERSON_ID := it_api.gen_pk;
end if;
:NEW.CREATED_ON := sysdate;
:NEW.CREATED_BY := nvl(v('APP_USER'),USER);
end if;
if updating then
:NEW.MODIFIED_ON := sysdate;
:NEW.MODIFIED_BY := nvl(v('APP_USER'),USER);
end if;
end;
```

Apart from this i want to create another trigger which would send email whenever new entry is made .
I deployed this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_NEW_PASSWORD" 
AFTER 
insert  on P_IT_PEOPLE
for each row 
DECLARE 
v_person_id number;
v_username varchar2(50);
v_Email varchar2(255);
Begin
select person_id,username,person_email into v_person_id,v_username,v_email from p_it_people where person_id=v_person_id;

             APEX_MAIL.SEND( 
                 p_to => v_email, 
                 p_from => v_email, 
                 p_body =>  'Your account has been created  ' ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Username'|| v_username||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Password'||v_username  ,
                  p_subj => 'New User'); 

end;
```

Now when i try inserting row, it is throwing error-p_it_people is mutating. How can i counter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting from the same table as the row-level trigger is firing on - exactly what causes "table is mutating".  But in this case you don't even need to.  Just use the :NEW pseudo-record like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_NEW_PASSWORD" 
AFTER 
insert  on P_IT_PEOPLE
for each row 
Begin
             APEX_MAIL.SEND( 
                 p_to => :NEW.person_email,
                 p_from => :NEW.person_email , 
                 p_body =>  'Your account has been created  ' ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Username'|| :NEW.username||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Password'||:NEW.username  ,
                  p_subj => 'New User'); 

end;
```

Comment: Also consider this in lieu of triggers for your audit information https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sequence-and-audit-columns-with-apex-5-and-12c/ Also bear in mind that even if you rollback your transaction, your email may have been sent.